# How can I "multi-thread" my storage migration script in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, automation, powercli

I've read a variety of resources covering **Start-Job** as a method for "multi-threading" a task but I am failing to figure out how to pass variables to it. I am using the PowerCLI cmdlet to migrate a large company's storage from an Old-Array to a New-Array. They have 7 sites across the US.

The idea for the migration automation is/was a multi-part ps1.
Part 1:

```
Define variables
Import-csv list-of-vms | foreach {
Count the active tasks
While count is at or over threshold, loop.
else
Run site specific ps1 (part 2)
sleep 60
Count
}
```

Part 2:

```
if target has move or is queued, exit.
else, move to New-Array
exit
```

What I need is a way to pass off the $_.vm from the Import-Csv to the Part 2 script... and an explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

So what you don't get is the use of Parameters with a script. There are plenty of guides and posts on the net that can explain how to use Parameters, but you could start by simply running `Get-Help about_parameters -full` in powershell. A quick and dirty example is:

```
Param(
    [String]$UserName,
    [String]$GroupName
)

$ADUser = Get-ADUser $UserName -prop MemberOf
If($GroupName -in $ADUser.MemberOf){"$UserName is a member of $GroupName"}
```

That allows the user to execute the script and specify a user and group and if the user is in the group it will say as much. Execution would be something like:

```
Script.ps1 -UserName 'TMTech' -GroupName 'CN=Administrators,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=ChinchillaFarm,DC=com'
```

That would check to see if the user 'TMTech' is in the Administrators group on the ChinchillaFarm.com domain. Unless you start getting into advanced parameter settings you can just pass in the parameters by position too, so that could be shortened to:

```
Script.ps1 'TMTech' 'CN=Administrators,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=ChinchillaFarm,DC=com'
```

Insert caveats! Your parameters must come first for the most part. The only things allowed to come before them in your script (or function, but let's not go there right now) are the `[cmdletbinding()]` line, and any comment based help that you want to have in your script.